# I am working on validating a contact form. Am i doing too much filtering?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, security

I am working on a contact form.
As the user types in an input field I check the input to see if its valid (with javascript in a function called validateInput()) and a bootstrap popover pops up if it is not valid.

The lastName field and subject field are not required. One question I have, are my regular expressions ok for these?(defined in window.onload)

Anyway, If the user submits the form, further tests are done to see if that data is valid.. (although it was already checked but just in case they ignored the popover).

If the data is indeed valid after pressing submit then the form data is sent to a contact_handler.php through an xmlhttp request.
when arriving there, the post data is checked to see if it is set.. if it is set then i use the filter_var function on the different post data. after that i use preg_replace to filter the names and message field to a limited set of characters.

Then I call a saveContactInfo() function i defined in contact_functions.php which inserts the data to a database.
My question is: Am I doing too much data filtering?.. is there such a thing as doing too much? I just want to make sure the data is safe.

Here is my code. There are lots of comments because it is a college assignment...

contact.html

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" maxlength="30" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" data-content="Must be at least 3 characters long, and must only contain letters and the following characters .'-" autofocus>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" maxlength="30" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" data-content="Must only contain letters and the following characters .'-" >
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email*</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" maxlength="254" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address.">
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" maxlength="200" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" data-content="Must only contain letters, numbers and the following characters .,'-?!=&quot;()">
                </div>              
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Message*</label>
                        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" maxlength="1000" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" data-content="A message with a minimum of 15 characters is required. Must only contain letters, numbers and characters such as .,'-?!=&quot;()" rows="4"></textarea>
                </div>
        <div id="form-message" class="form-group">  
            <p></p>
        </div> 
        <!--give the button an id of submitButton so we can add a click event listener to it in our javascript-->
                <button id="submitButton" type="button"class="btn btn-orange"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Submit</button>

    </div>                   
</form>
```

javascript at the bottom of contact.html

```
<script>

//declare global variables
var firstNameRegex;
var lastNameRegex;
var subjectRegex;
var emailRegex;
var messageRegex;
var xmlhttpContact;

window.onload = function(){
    /*this function is implemented after the page is fully loaded.
     *the first name field should be a minimum of 3 characters and should only contain letters and certain special characters
     *such as full stop, apostrophe, and hyphen.
     */
    firstNameRegex = /^([A-Za-z .'-]{3,})$/;

    /*The last name field should be a minimum of 0 characters as it is not a required field, 
     *and should only contain letters and certain special characters such as full stop, apostrophe, and hyphen.
     */
    lastNameRegex = /^([A-Za-z .'-]{0,})$/;


    /*The subject field is optional so can therefore be a minium of 0 characters.
     *If any characters are entered in this field they should only be letters, numbers or certain special characters 
     *limited to the full stop, apostrophe, and hyphen characters.
     */
    subjectRegex = /^([A-Za-z0-9 .,'-?!="()]{0,})$/;

    //The email address entered by the user, will be tested against the following regular expression.
    //This regular expression for an email address is recommended in the W3C HTML5 specification. (See reference at top of this page.)
    emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

    //The message entered by the user, will be tested against the following regular expression.
    //There is a minimum of 15 characters required in the message.
    messageRegex = /^([A-Za-z0-9 .,'-?!="()]{15,})$/; 


    //add a 'click' event listener to our submit button. When the button is pressed we will call the subitForm() function
    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', submitForm, false);

    //call the validateInput() function which we have defined below and pass the id of the input fields and their corresponding 
    //regular expression values as parameters.
    validateInput('first-name', firstNameRegex);
    validateInput('last-name', lastNameRegex);
    validateInput('subject', subjectRegex);
    validateInput('email', emailRegex);
    validateInput('message', messageRegex);

    //remove the form error and success messages when 'keypress' or 'focus' events occur on input or textarea fields.
    removeFormMessages();
}

function validateInput(inputID, regularExpression){
    /*This is a function which takes in the id of an input field or textarea and a regular expression as parameters.
     *In this function we test the value of the input field (or textarea) against the regular expression 
     *which we have defined for that input type to make sure the input is valid.
     *For example if we are taking in the users 'first name' as input, then we will test this against the 
     *regular expression we have defined for a valid first name (in the indow.onload function).
     *If it is NOT valid then we display a popover message to the user. 
     *If input IS valid then we hide the popover. This gives immediate feedback to the user during the process of filling
     *out the form.
     */

    //we listen for the following events on the input field or textarea that was passed as a parameter.
    //'keyup', 'keypress', 'blur', 'change' 
    //The input entered in that field is checked for validity when these events occur.
    //If it is not valid, then the popover with error message is displayed until input is validated.

    $('#' + inputID).on('keyup keypress blur change', function(){
        //store the value of our input field into a javascript variable called inputValue
        var inputValue = document.getElementById(inputID).value;

        //Now we test our inputValue against the appropriate regular expression (which we took in as a parameter).
        //the javascript test() function which we use here will return true if the input matches the regular expression
        //and false if not.
        //We store the boolean result into the variable isInputValid
        var isInputValid = regularExpression.test(inputValue);

        if(!isInputValid){  
        //If input is not valid go here
            if(!$(this).hasClass('isShowing')){
                //if our popover error does not have class isShowing then do the following
                //show popover and add class isShowing to the element so that we know what state it is in.
                $(this).popover('show');
                $(this).addClass('isShowing');
            }
            //else if our popover error is already showing then leave it showing (ie do nothing here).
        }else{
        //If input is valid go here
            if($(this).hasClass('isShowing')){
                //if our popover error has class isShowing then do the following
                //hide popover and remove isShowing class so we know it is hidden now
                $(this).popover('hide');
                $(this).removeClass('isShowing');
            }
            //else if our popover error is already hidden then leave it hidden.
        }
    });
}
function removeFormMessages(){
    /*This function listens for a 'keypress' or a 'focus' event on input and textarea fields
     *and when it detects these events it hides the form-message paragraph.
     *We do this because, If a user has submitted the form and then been notified that the 'form is invalid' 
     *and goes back to change his/her input then we assume they have seen the error message 
     *so we delete it so that the next time they are notified of something it will be easier to see.
     */
    $('input, textarea').on('keypress focus', function(){
        $("#form-message p").hide();
        $("#form-message p").removeClass('animated').removeClass('bounce');
        $("#form-message p").html('');
    });
}
function hideAllPopovers(){
    /*this function hides all popovers that are currently showing on input fields or textareas.
     *We will call this function after the form is submitted, if all fields are valid.
     */
    $('input, textarea').popover('hide');
    $('input, textarea').removeClass('isShowing');
}
function submitForm(){
    //get the values of all input and textarea fields in the contact form
    var firstName = document.getElementById('first-name').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('last-name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    //we need to check the validity of the input values in case the user has ignored our popover error messages
    //therefore test (again) the values the user entered against regular expressions which we defined earlier for different types of input.
    //and store the boolean results into variables.
    var isfirstNameValid = firstNameRegex.test(firstName);
    var islastNameValid = lastNameRegex.test(lastName);
    var isSubjectValid = subjectRegex.test(subject); 
    var isEmailValid = emailRegex.test(email); 
    var isMessageValid = messageRegex.test(message);

    if((!isfirstNameValid) || (!islastNameValid) ||(!isEmailValid) ||(!isSubjectValid) || (!isMessageValid)){
        //If any of the values entered to the input fields are invalid then show an error message to the user.
        //And do not allow the form to be submitted
        //We use the error-text class for red text.
        $("#form-message p").html('<span class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> The form is not valid!</span>');
        $("#form-message p").show();
        $("#form-message p").addClass('animated').addClass('bounce');
    }else{
        //If form input is valid then firstly hide any popovers which are showing
        hideAllPopovers();

        //then we create a new xmlhttp request.
        xmlhttpContact = createXHR();

        xmlhttpContact.onreadystatechange = contactCallback; //when the response comes back call the contactCallback function
        //Send our form values to the contact_handler.php page by POST 
        xmlhttpContact.open("POST", "contact_handler.php" ,true);   
        xmlhttpContact.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //send our variables to the contact_handler.php page by POST
        xmlhttpContact.send("firstName=" + firstName + "&lastName=" + lastName + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message);

    }
}

function contactCallback(){
    //this function will be called when we receive a response back from the xmlhttp request.
    if(xmlhttpContact.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpContact.status == 200){

        //store the response text into a variable called message.
        var message = xmlhttpContact.responseText;

        //clear any text in the input fields.
        $('input, textarea').val('');
        //insert our message to the form-message paragraph tag
        $("#form-message p").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> ' + message);
        $("#form-message p").show();
        //we use the bootstrap animation classes to create an animation on the message text.
        $("#form-message p").addClass('animated').addClass('bounce');

    }
}
</script>
```

contact_handler.php

```
<?php
//check if all the required fields are set
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
    //collect the post data if the contact form has been submitted and store it into local variables

    //Remove all HTML tags from $_POST["firstName"] and store it into variable $firstName
    $firstName = filter_var($_POST["firstName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

    if(isset($_POST['lastName'])){
        //check if lastName isset before filtering it.
        //Remove all HTML tags from $_POST["lastName"] and store it into variable $lastName
        $lastName = filter_var($_POST["lastName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    }

    //Remove illegal characters from $_POST["email"]
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 

    if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
        //check if subject isset before filtering it.
        //Remove all HTML tags from $_POST["subject"] and store it into variable $subject
        $subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    }

    //Remove all HTML tags from $_POST["message"] and store it into variable $message
    $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

    //do further filtering with preg_replace for extra security.
    $firstName = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z .'-]#i", "", $firstName); //filter everything but letters and a few special characters.
    $lastName = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z .'-]#i", "", $lastName); //filter everything but letters and a few special characters.
    $subject = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z0-9 .,'-?!=\"()]#i", "", $subject); //filter everything but numbers, letters and a few special characters.
    $message = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z0-9 .,'-?!=\"()]#i", "", $message); //filter everything but numbers, letters and a few special characters.


    //store the boolean result of saveContactInfo function into a variable called $messageSent
    $messageSent = saveContactInfo($firstName, $lastName, $email, $subject, $message, $pdoConnection);//this method is defined in contact_functions.php
    if($messageSent){
        //if saveContactInfo returns true then we know the data has been entered to the database so we inform the user that
        //the message has been sent. This message will be echoed back to our ajax callback method in contact.html 
        //where we will insert it to the HTML.
        echo 'Your Message has been sent!!';
    }
}
?>
```

contact_functions.php

```
<?php
function saveContactInfo($firstName, $lastName, $email, $subject, $message, $pdoConnection){
    $messageTime = time(); //Get timestamp of current time and store it into a variable

    try{
        $query ="INSERT INTO contact_info (firstName, lastName, email, subject, message, messageTime) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :email, :subject, :message, :messageTime)";
        $statement = $pdoConnection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $statement->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $statement->bindValue(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $statement->bindValue(':messageTime', $messageTime, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $statement->execute();
        return true;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        //throw new pdoDbException($e); 
        return "Error message " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If it works, it works. It depends on you on how thorough you want your validation is.

Comment: what about people with names like `Lu/Xu`? What about non-latin symbols? Message cannot contain greater/smaller signs?

Comment: It's best practice to validate both on the client side and the server side. It's only "too much" if your validation unintentionally alters the data and makes it invalid or unrecognizable to the user. If it changes dramatically, you'll want to notify the user somehow of the data that actually made it through.

Comment: Generally I think the only reason to filter things is if you can guarantee they are never going to be valid in any situation. With things like names, there are so many weird outliers that filtering correctly is very difficult.

Comment: There's also a really good article that demonstrates this exact issue. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Patrick Gregorio thanks do you think i could leave out the preg_replace() filtering that i am doing in the contact_handler.php and the data would be safe enough by just using filter_var()?

Comment: @IarsAnders thanks do you think i could leave out the preg_replace() filtering that i am doing in the contact_handler.php and the data would be safe enough by just using filter_var()?

Answer (score 1):

> is there such a thing as doing too much?

Certainly yes, anything can be done an absurd amount of times to become "too much."

> Am I doing too much data filtering?

I would say yes but, the question is pretty vacuous. I'll interpret this to mean 'am I doing the most meaningful validation?". You are doing too much validation because you are validating in the front and the back end. For something that's just going to be on a query-string to `contact_handler.php` you might just want to do everything in the back-end because anyone can bypass your javascript and type in the query string by hand.

That doesn't wholly mean not to validate on the front end. In practice I usually only do one type of validation on the front end to make sure all the form's fields are filled in.

All the validation for length and content I do on the back end, sending back any errors in the response to the xhr request. Of course re-validating the presence of fields in the query-string is a must as anybody could send a request with an unexpected query-string by hand.

I avoid front-end validation until after the back-end is rock solid.

Comment: I was doing front end validation for a better user experience. the popovers would give them immediate feedback on the validity of what they are typing. its not being sent by query string-its post data... thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Right sorry, it use the message body, GET uses qs.